# How is the gmail sync interval determined on Android?

Tags: sync, gmail

Today I stopped getting notifications for gmail messages received on Android. This has happened before and always seems to fix itself after a day or two, but I want to find out why. So I looked under

```
(Main phone settings) > Cloud and accounts > Accounts > Google
```

and indeed I see all the Google apps like this

```
Sync Calendar (On) / Last synced on 4/27/21 07:50  [8 hours ago]
Sync Chrome (Off) / Sync turned off
...
Sync Drive (On) / Last synced on 4/25/21 10:36  [2 days ago]
Sync Gmail (On) / Last synced on 4/27/21 07:50  [8 hours ago]  <-- this must be the problem
...
```

In the past, Sync Gmail would show that it last synced just a minute ago. Why did this change? How can I set it back? The only setting I can find is to turn sync off entirely, and then turn it back on. Ok, this syncs once when I do it but doesn't continue to sync. I want it to sync automatically every few minutes like it normally does.

Comment: Have you enabled on Gmail settings -> your email account -> Sync Gmail?

Comment: From my understanding Gmail app in combination with. Gmail account uses Google proprietary protocols for notifications such as Google push notification service. I would assume that this service always fails when Google has again a big outage. I do remember having read that some Google services failed in the last days. May be you were affected?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes, that is enabled